# HTTP request using threading from iphone

Tags: iphone, httpwebrequest, multithreading

Can anyone point out a turorial which explains threading?? In my application, i'm uploading some data (even large sized images) to the servelet. The uploading process may take quite a large time depending on the bandwidth, as usual. So i need to implement threading in it so that the uploading process takes place in the background. Any experts here, may please post an example or a tutorial link or something like that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple and robust way of launching background tasks is using [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html). It allows you to create a class (inherited from NSOperation) that represents a task which can be placed in a threaded queue which is handled in the background.

[NSOperationQueue documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Another easy way of launching something in the background is by using the **performSelectorInBackground** method:

```
- (void) launchTask {
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundTask) withObject:nil];
}

- (void) backgroundTask {
   // stuff to do in background
}
```

Comment: but when i implement this, a problem is occurring; if i give to laucnh this task, it works fine for the first time, but if i try to call it again while the first one running, the newer is executed and the other is just lost. What i came to know is to queue them, but don't know to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see an actual implementation of this, take a look at the source code for [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

Comment: For his application, it sounds like he should just use that wrapper and not worry about the underlying threading himself.