# UIActivityIndicator not showing up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I have implemented a UIActivityIndicator that shows up in one part of my program but not another. I have the activity indicator come up while i am loading a table, however, i am trying to get it to start animating again after the user has clicked a button and is waiting for the table to reload. The table reloads, but no indicator. Here is the code.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake (120.0, 185.0, 80, 80);
    activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
    activity.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
    [activity startAnimating];

    [navigationUpdateFromDetail.window addSubview: activity];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

It comes up for that part. However, for the next part it does not want to seem to come up.

```
- (IBAction) btnGreaterTen_clicked :(id)sender {

    self.searchDistance = [NSNumber numberWithDouble : 10];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake (120.0, 185.0, 80, 80);

    activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
    activity.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;

    [navigationUpdateFromDetail.window addSubview: activity];
    [activity startAnimating];


    NSLog(@" search value after change %@", [searchDistance description]);

    [self getSetDisplay];

    [activity stopAnimating];
}
```

That button changes a variable and is suppose to start the animation, but it does not. I have changed the color to make sure it was not just blending in, so that is not the solution. I tried to recreate the same object, but still no luck.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: when will your indicator stop animating in the first case?

Comment: it stops right after the getSetDisplay is finished

Comment: See my answer. Your solution can never work.

Comment: oh, i apologize, I didnt include that part in the code, but it stops in the -(void)viewDidAppear method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work, because the animation will only show when the main application loop is "running". In your code, you're blocking the main thread by calling [self getSetDisplay].

You should load your data asynchronously to make this work (in a background thread). Then you can call **startAnimating**, start your thread, and when the thread finishes, stop the animation.

Comment: im not quite sure what you mean by loading it in the background, I call  [self getSetDisplay] after starting the animation. Isnt the main thread running its loop then?

Comment: From what you are saying, it makes sense cause the first activity indicator is called in the -viewWillAppear method which is running on the main loop. My functions are not. So do i need to implement a different function all together?

Comment: This solution is correct. I removed the [self getSetDisplay] function and kept the activity indicator running and it popped up. but im still at a loss as to how to fix it.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879248/http-request-using-threading-from-iphone or check out the threading documentation on Apple's developer site:http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thank you, I got the implementation for the "performinbackground" class, however i cannot seem to find how to monitor for the call back. How exactly do you know its done?

Answer (score 1):

This has been bugging me for ages, and I just found that when using a search display controller I had to add the activity indicator as a subview of the search results to get it to show.  In my viewDidLoad, I put...

```
// create activity indicator
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f)];
[activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

When I want to start animating, i put...

```
[activityIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.frame.size.width/2.0f, self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.frame.size.height/2.0f)];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

try adding

```
activity.hidden = NO;
```

just before

```
[activity startAnimating];
```