# activity indicator is not display

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

```
-(IBAction)actionPrevious:(id)sender{

    [self startact];
    pageNumber = pageNumber - 1;

    if (pageNumber>0) { 
        NSString *str_Img =[array_Image objectAtIndex:pageNumber];  
        NSData *mydata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str_Img]];
        UIImage *myimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:mydata];
        [imageView1 setImage:myimage];
        [self.view addSubview:imageView1];
        lbl_PhotoName.text = [array_Name objectAtIndex:pageNumber];
        lbl_PhotoDate.text = [array_Date objectAtIndex:pageNumber];
        lbl_PhotoDesc.text = [array_Desc objectAtIndex:pageNumber];
        [mydata release];
        [myimage release];
    }
    [self endact];

}

-(void)startact{
        [act setHidden:NO];
        [act startAnimating];

}

-(void)endact{
    [act stopAnimating];
    [act setHidden:YES];
}
```

In above code activity activity indicator is not display. Photo are display using the web service. please Help!
Thank You

Comment: Please post code where you initialize act

Comment: Please tell me you linked it in IB...

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIActivityIndicator not showing up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984487/uiactivityindicator-not-showing-up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work on the same thread and need to call by this way

```
[self performSelector:@selector(startact) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
```

Comment: You need to call it before loading the images.And if it helped you then don't forget to accept the answer and vote me up.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use threading in these kinds of scenarios.

Because `activity indicator` is on same thread as of the images work; thats why it is creating problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a silly mistake that I always seem to make: If you added the activity indicator programmatically did you make sure to addSubview: ? Or maybe it's hidden by something? Everything else looks fine, and you definitely don't need to startAnimating in a separate thread.